# Add sparklines pie chart to Jquery DataTable from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datatables, sparklines

I am trying to make `sparklines` pie-charts render in `JQuery Datatables` dynamically. I can add a `JQuery sparklines` piechart into `JQuery DataTable` like this:

```
                                                    <table id="dt-basic-example"
                                                       class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped w-100">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>pie_chart</th>
                                                     
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                             <span class="sparklines" sparkType="pie" sparkHeight="50" sparkWidth="auto" values="4,6,7,7,4"> </span>
                                                            </td> 
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
```

How can I add the same pie chart when `$(document).ready()` ?

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
    var myData = [
    {
        pie_chart: '<span class="sparklines" sparkType="pie" sparkHeight="50" sparkWidth="auto" values="4,6,7,7,4"> </span>'
    }
];


$(function () {
    $('#dt-basic-example').dataTable({
        data: myData,
        columns: [
            {data: 'pie_chart'}
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I added class to my `sparkline` element and re-draw it with new values.

```
var myData = [
    {
        pie_chart: '<span class="sparklines top10" sparkType="pie" sparkHeight="50" sparkWidth="auto" values="4,6,7,7,4"> </span>'
    },



        $('#dt-basic-example').dataTable({
        data: myData,
        columns: [
            {data: 'pie_chart'},
        ],
        responsive: true,
        searching: false,
        paging: false,
        info: false
    });
    $('.top10').sparkline([1, 2, 3, 4], {
        type: 'pie',
        height: '50',
        width: '50'
    });
```

Comment: Is this a solution to your problem? If so, that's great! - but maybe you can edit your answer and provide a few words to explain how it fixed the problem.

Comment: @andrewjames yes. Okay

Comment: You need to edit your _answer_, not your question.